# What's the difference between normal and Christmas beer?

Tags: occasions

What's the difference between normal and Christmas beer? What makes them special?

Answer (score 9):

A Christmas Ale seems to be another term for a "[Winter Warmer](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style21.php#1b)" beer -- a dark, malty beer (raisins, dark fruit) meant to be enjoyed in colder months, with a warming effect, either from the actual alcohol, or spices it was brewed with (think nutmeg, clove, that sort of thing).  To my mind, its kindred to a barley wine, just spiced up.  This is *not* a warm summer day, sitting on the porch, type of beer, as you may have guessed.

So a Christmas Ale is a sub-classification of beers in general.

Comment: But what if Christmas IS in the middle of summer... Like for the whole Southern Hemisphere? :)

Answer (score 0):

**What's the difference between normal and Christmas beer?**

Beer may be beer to most people, but in Norway the Christmas beer par excellent is the juleøl:

> The drink par excellence is the juleøl, the Christmas beer. **It is a sweeter than usual beer that norwegians usually drink at Christmas and that is supposed to be good with the big meals.** The other traditional drink at this time of the year is the gløgg, mulled wine with spices that people have with almonds and raisins. - [The tradition of Julebord in Norway](https://sayhitonorway.com/2015/12/11/the-tradition-of-julebord-in-norway/)

[image: Christmas beer]

[Christmas beer](https://sayhitonorway.com/2015/12/11/the-tradition-of-julebord-in-norway/)

Answer (score -1):

Christmas beer are seasonal beers brewed for consumption during Christmas period. These beers  often (but not always) contain more alcohol than the brewery's other types of beer and may also contain spicing. It is usually quite dark, but not as dark as a stout, with a big malt presence.

Comment: Not all Christmas beers are higher in alcohol content - but most do indeed contain spices and seasonal blends. Spices such as cinnamon, nutmeg, chocolate, etc...

Comment: Cool a downvote without explanation. Constructive people being constructive.

Comment: And I like the comment restating exactly what was said in the answer.

Comment: Actually I modified that after the comment :)

Comment: Perhaps the negative voter was upset that you posted a question with an answer ready?

Comment: @Greg No, the negative voter, (who, I will add, finds grousing about downvotes sans comments to be the single most offensive thing *anyone* can do on SE short of posting flat out hate speech), voted down the answer because he felt that it wasn't a very good answer, and didn't do a particularly good job of articulating what makes the "Winter Warmer"/"Christmas Ale" style unique. That said, the pejorative use of the 'r-word' has managed to rile me up even more than your complaining about my downvote, so good job!

Comment: This answer feels like it should be an edit to the original question, since it doesn't answer the question and is more of a clarification on the question